# how can I make a custom overlay filter?

Tags: ios, filter, uiimageview

I have a viewController with a UIImageView. The imageView is to be loaded with a different random picture from a given array when the viewController is displayed. Above the UIImageView I would like to implement a filter similar to one I found in photoshop but with my own custom modification for a clear window to the image below. Basically, what I am looking to do is display a random image behind a blurred filter but I would like a part of the blur filter to have a custom shaped window to the image below it where the image can be seen clearly. The rest of the image would still be blurred out. I have read apples documentation for applying filters to images but none of them suit my needs. Pretty new to development and haven't written any code for this feature yet. I'm more looking to see if it can be done and if so, could you point me in the direction of where I can research to find the answers I'm looking for? cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you take the input image, pass it through a [`CIGaussianBlur`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html), then I'd draw the image applying an image mask (using [`CIBlendWithMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithMask) or a [`CGPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html).)

Comment: I didn't think about that. But you're right, the combination of the two will give me what I am looking for. Now, to figure out how its all done! ha. thanks!